# Time Complexity of binary search in java

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, binary-search

How can we calculate the complexity of the following java code with line by line analysis

```
1    int[] data;
2    int size;
3
4    public boolean binarySearch(int key) 
5    {
6         int low = 0;
7         int high = size - 1;
8          
9         while(high >= low) {
10             int middle = (low + high) / 2;
11             if(data[middle] == key) {
12                 return true;
13             }
14             if(data[middle] < key) {
15                 low = middle + 1;
16             }
17             if(data[middle] > key) {
18                 high = middle - 1;
19             }
20        }
21        return false;
22   }
```

Comment: Any binary search tutorial would describe it in detail! I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because user didn't try searching it on Web first.

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is to note that at each step we either halve the size of the interval we are searching or we break out of the while loop because we-ve found the element we've been looking for. If the initial size if `n`, then we do halve it at most `log_2 n` by the definition of the logarithm. In each iteration we spend `O(1)` time, so the total running time is `O(log n)` where `n` is the size of the interval we're searching.

More formally you can write this as `T(n) = T(n/2)+O(1)` for `n>1` and `T(1) = O(1)`, which solves to `T(n) = O(log n)`.

Comment: My concern is that we not only have to go through the loop logN times but for example we have to make operations such as middle=(high+low)/2 which takes approximately linear time complexity therefore shouldn't the time complexity be something line O((logN)^2) or O(NlogN)?

Comment: Aha, so you want to take into accout the cost of arithmetic operations as well?

Comment: Well, in that case, addition takes time `O(log max(high,low))=O(log N)` and dividing by two can be done in a single bit shift, i.e. `a/2` is equivalent to `a >>= 2`, so each iteration takes `O(log N)` time; altogether this is `O((log N)^2)`, as you said.

Comment: @ElioNushi the thing to remember is that the time for the arithmetic operations is _linear **in the number of bits**_, so computing `N+N` takes `O(log N)` time.